# Split cell with multiple lines into rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with cells that have linebreaks (entered via ALT + ENTER).

I have to separate them into individual rows. All the cells are in column A.

Each line in the cell has a bullet point (eg. "* ") up front, which could serve as a beacon to break the line at this point.

[image]

Comment: You can use the Split function Split(Cells(i,1),, "*"), and keep looping down column A (starting with i=1, adding 1 to move down), output into another column

Comment: Split using `VbLf` as delimiter instead or `*` that way you can have those bullets as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split with Chr(10) or VbLf

```
Dim cell_value As Variant
Dim counter As Integer

'Row counter
counter = 1

'Looping trough A column define max value
For i = 1 To 10

    'Take cell at the time
    cell_value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

    'Split cell contents
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    WrdArray() = Split(cell_value, vbLf)

    'Place values to the B column
    For Each Item In WrdArray
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 2).Value = Item
        counter = counter + 1
    Next Item


Next i
```

No you have array to place each row to different cell

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of code for this, lets make it simple.

Follow the bellow steps.

Select the data-set you want to split -> Go to Data Tab -> Select "Text to columns" -> from this pop-up select "Delimited" -> Select which delimiter is separating your texts -> Select the destination cell -> Click "OK"

Try This.

Regards,
Ashwin

Edit from Markus: For the newline as delimiter use "Ctr-J"

Comment: That would split into columns, not rows, moreover there is no possibility to define vbCrLf as a separator.

Comment: You could simply add another step to @Ashwin's solution by copying the data (after separating it into columns), right click the cell under the first one, select Paste Special, and choose Transpose. But if the workbook is 'full with cells' (as stated) it's not the best solution. VBA is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the cell and run the macro you would get what you want on the next column like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub selection_into_rows()


    Dim k           As Variant
    Dim l_counter   As Long

    k = Split(Selection, Chr(10))

    For l_counter = LBound(k) To UBound(k)
        Cells(l_counter + 1, Selection.Column + 1) = k(l_counter)
    Next l_counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on one row only after selecting it (but should get you started):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectionIntoRows()

Dim k() As String
Dim l As Long
Dim i As Long

k() = Split(Range("A1"), " ")
i = 1
For l = 0 To UBound(k)
    Cells(i, 1) = k(l)
    i = i + 1
Next l

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub extract()

'Query extract data in cell B divided by ALT+Enter, Comma space
'Mandatory to create in front Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3
'ATTENTION! if field B is empty return no data!! Manually add column A (with empty column B)if needed!!
'manually remove empty cell in results (Sheet2)
'before START Query remove duplicate from input data!!
'Doesn't work with full stop
'When finished Msg Done will be display

Dim c As Long, r As Range, I As Long, d As Long, Temp() As String
    d = 0
    For Each r In Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)    ' Change this to suit your range..
        c = 2
        Temp = Split((r.Value), Chr(10))
        For i = LBound(Temp) To UBound(Temp)

```
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r.Row, c - 1).Offset(d, 0).Value = Cells(r.Row, r.Column - 1).Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r.Row, c).Offset(d, 0).Value = Temp(i)
        Cells(r.Row, c).Offset(d, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Trim(ActiveCell.Value)
        d = d + 1
    Next
    d = d - 1
Next
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$62856").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), _
    Header:=xlYes
Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a half dozen of these blobs from an poor Acrobat PDF to XLSX conversion, peppered throughout 500 rows.
I copied the text blob (like OP) into Notepad, removed "" from the start and end line, and pasted to a new spreadsheet.  That tells me how many lines to insert.  Then pasted into that hole.

"This was all of
my input text"

Then I could use TextToCol.