# Excel Split cell with multiple lines into rows for entire table

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel (2016), I have some data that looks like this:

[image]

Based on a particular column, in this example the 'IPAddress' column, if there are multiple lines in the cell, separate the string into a new row and copy the remaining data into that row.

This is what I am looking for after the script or whatever completes.

[image]

I'm using the follow code from: [Split cell with multiple lines into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835884/split-cell-with-multiple-lines-into-rows)

```
    Sub tes_5()


    Dim cell_value As Variant
    Dim counter As Integer

    'Row counter
    counter = 1

    'Looping trough A column define max value
    For i = 1 To 10

        'Take cell at the time
        cell_value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value

        'Split cell contents
        Dim WrdArray() As String
        WrdArray() = Split(cell_value, vbLf)

        'Place values to the B column
        For Each Item In WrdArray
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 2).Value = Item
            counter = counter + 1
        Next Item


    Next i
End Sub
```

That separates out the IPAddress column, but does not add the data for the other cells in the new row.

Text to columns doesn't work and Power Query (https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-in-excel-to-bulk-split-cells-with-multiple-lines-inside-into-new-rows-without-overwriting-the-existing-data-below) doesn't work either.

Any other suggestions?

Update:
Just learned that by default, Excel puts a comma at the beginning of the delimiter field, which was causing my delimiter to not work when choosing line feed.
[image]

If you remove the leading comma, you "should" (like I did), get the desired results.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple with Power Query

All you need to do is split the `IPAddress` column by the linefeed character into Rows

**Split Column dialog from UI**

[image]

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Server Name", type text}, {"Serial Number", type text}, {"OS", type text}, {"IPAddress", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"IPAddress", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "IPAddress")
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Comment: Excel puts a leading comma (by default) in the delimiter text field.  Once I removed that, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming your data starts in A2:

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long, v As Variant

For r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    v = Split(Cells(r, 4), vbLf)
    If UBound(v) > 0 Then
        Cells(r + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(v), 4).Insert shift:=xlDown
        Cells(r + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(v), 3).Value = Cells(r, 1).Resize(, 3).Value
        Cells(r, 4).Resize(UBound(v) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(v)
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```